# prevent user enter account page without log in and restrict users pages to visit

Tags: php

Good day again. Im trying to create a system with different users. Client, Laboratory Assistant, Personnel and the admin. What I want is i want to restrict the users visit the pages which they don't belong. E.g(Client visiting admin pages).

**Here is code i tried to each page but still can visit every any page.**

```
    session_start();
if($_SESSION['Classification'] == 'Client') { 
    header('Client-home.php'); 
} else if($_SESSION['Classification'] == 'Computer Laboratory Assistant') { 
    header('la-home.php'); 
}else if($_SESSION['Classification'] == 'Personnel') { 
    header('personnel-home.php'); 
}else { 
    header('admin.php'); }
```

**Any help is much appreciated.**

```
<?php
session_start();
include("connect.php");
include("function.php");
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['password'] = $password;
$idUser = $_SESSION['idUser'];
//$username = stripslashes($username);
//$password = stripslashes($password);
//$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
//$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$password'";
$SelQuery = $executeQuery = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row_User = mysql_fetch_assoc($SelQuery);
$_SESSION['idUser'] = $row_User['idUser'];
$_SESSION['lName'] = $row_User['lName'];
$_SESSION['fName'] = $row_User['fName'];

if($row_User['Classification'] == 'Client'){
    header("Location: client-home.php");
}elseif($row_User['Classification'] == 'Personnel'){
    header("Location: personnel-home.php ");
}elseif($row_User['Classification'] == 'Administrator'){
    header("Location: admin.php");
}else{
    header("Location: login_error.php");
}
```

?>

**This is my login page. I guess this cause the conflicts**

Comment: well, there is a problem with that, because if the `$_SESSION['Classification']` goes wrong in anyway, the user will have admin privilege.

Comment: What should i do then?

Comment: the problem is if you will make a mistake in making the sessions, then the users can go to admin.php, you are using mysql? or just sessions?

Comment: The session is not working

Comment: add the code that your making the sessions so we could help

Comment: I edited and include my login page that may cause the conflict, i hope  it may guide you to help me.

Answer (score 1):

On your `Client-home.php` and other files you need to implement the same...

`Client-home.php`

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['Classification'] != 'Client')
{
header("Location : Noaccess.php");
exit;
}
```

Comment: I see. What should include in Noaccess.php?

Comment: The `Noaccess.php` is just an illustration I showed you.. Its like an error page to tell the end-user that he is not allowed to access that page.

Comment: this is the best way, but its messy if you have lots of pages, and you need to implement that code to each one of them.

Comment: Or should i redirect it to login page?

Comment: its up to you, you can redirect to login page, or show them an error page, what ever suits you.

Comment: It's not working. And i tried to echo the $_SESSION['Classification'] and it displays nothing, so i guess there is no $_SESSION['Classification']

Comment: That has nothing to do with the above code. You need to check whether you are properly setting `$_SESSION['Classification'] = 'something';` when the user is successfully logged in. I assume you should check your `login.php` for that.

Comment: I edited my question and include my login page that may cause the conflict, i hope  it may guide you to help me.